# TFS: How to check a DateTime field in Field Definition Rule's When

Tags: datetime, tfs, field, workflow, rule

In a Work Item Template -> Workflow, in TFS 2012, I want to create a When/Copy rule on a Transition.
When a DateTime field is empty it should copy value from one field to another.
It seems that the When condition can only take a string value to compare.  Is this correct?
I have tried using both empty value and DateTime.MinValue but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is my XML for this field:

```
<FieldReference refname="System.AssignedTo">
  <COPY from="value" value="TestDepartment" />
  <WHEN field="MyCreationDate" value="">
    <COPY from="field" field="System.CreatedBy" />
  </WHEN>
</FieldReference>
```

**Updated:**
It seems the check for empty value for DateTime is working.  It is only copying into AssignedTo that is not working.  If I choose a dummy string instead of a field value (inside the when condition) it gets copied into AssignedTo.

Comment: maybe if you're using this rule in the initial transition, this may occur because the "System.CreatedBy" has no value during the transition, only when the transition completes. But other than that, I don't know why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up with finding another field I could check.
So now I have 2 WHEN clauses and it works.

```
<FieldReference refname="System.AssignedTo">
  <WHEN field="OwnerFieldString" value="">
    <COPY from="field" field="System.CreatedBy" />
  </WHEN>
  <WHEN field="System.CreatedBy" value="Creator Name">
    <COPY from="value" value="TestDepartment" />
  </WHEN>
</FieldReference>
```